# jQuery creating a rotate wheel menu

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create rotate wheel menu.

This i my image :
     [menu http://sabanto.xyz/jqui/images/menu.png](http://sabanto.xyz/jqui/images/menu.png)

I need to be able to scroll the wheel and click the wheel.

Every quarter the on click url will change according to an array of urls.

Any ideas where can i start?

Thanks allot

Avi

Comment: I propose that you start off with mapping the clickable areas on an image map. Then you can try turn the wheel with css3 transition.

Answer (score 0):

check this solution:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="http://sabanto.xyz/jqui/images/menu.png" id="img"  usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://stackoverflow.com" shape="poly" coords="390,54,393,403,729,393,690,229,590,117,501,74" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://stackoverflow.com" shape="poly" coords="395,404,396,728,546,696,655,604,715,490,729,394" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://stackoverflow.com" shape="poly" coords="394,727,392,403,57,395,87,532,156,635,262,704" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://stackoverflow.com" shape="poly" coords="389,55,392,401,57,392,77,274,130,185,213,106,304,70" />

</map>

<a class="left" href="javascript:"> <- </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="right" href="javascript:"> -> </a>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        var deg = 0

        $('.right').click(function(){
            deg=deg+20; 
            rotate(deg);                   
        })
        $('.left').click(function(){
            deg=deg-20;  
            rotate(deg);                  
        })

        function rotate(deg)
        {
            $('#img').css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+deg+'deg)');
            $('#img').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+deg+'deg)');
            $('#img').css('-o-transform:', 'rotate('+deg+'deg)');
            $('#img').css('-ms-transform:', 'rotate('+deg+'deg)');
        }     

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8mfduzgr)

Comment: wow it's amazing...
is there a way to spin the wheel by touching and draging?

Comment: yes, but when you click to drag it will activate link